# Problem with using htmlunit driver for Selenium

Tags: htmlunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the htmlunit driver with selenium 2 but when the following call is made in my test:

driver.get(startPage);

It returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body/>
</html>
```

as the source page when I then call driver.getPageSource();

Does anyone have any idea why Selenium isn't downloading the full source for my page?

Comment: how does your code begin? It seems like you haven't navigated to a page yet

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the code below:

```
        ICapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit();
        IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(desiredCapabilities);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");

        string a = driver.PageSource;
```

now the entire source code of the webpage is stored on the variable 'a'.